# How to reformulate an objective function with absolute

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have the following optimization problem:

$min_{w} \sum^{N}_{i=1} |\mu_i| \cdot log(|w_i|) $ s.t.

$\sqrt{w' \cdot \Sigma \cdot w} \leq 0.05$

$w_i > 0 $ if $\mu_i > 0$

$w_i < 0 $ if $\mu_i < 0$

$\sum^{N}_{i=1} |w_i| = 1$

The optimization algorithm that I have chosen is [SQP](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/constrained-nonlinear-optimization-algorithms.html#f26622) (for reasons not discussed here). However, this algorithm requires smooth objective functions that are *continous* and *differentiable*. As I have the absolute and log in my function, this requirement seems to be violated.

I understand that then the general practice is to reformulate this problem. I am however puzzled how to do this. How could this problem be reformulated? Where do you start?

Comment: Besides smoothness there are also convexity issues to worry about. This can not be answered in just a sentence or two.

Comment: Ok but modern optimizers are unable to handle this?

Comment: A modern SQP solver will still use an SQP algorithm which comes with certain assumptions. The age of a solver does not magically change mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here that $\mu_i$ is constant. Here is a possible formulation:

Let $s_i = \text{sign}(\mu_i)$ and $\varepsilon=10^{-6}$

NLP:
$$\begin{align} 
   \min & \sum_i |\mu_i| \log(\varepsilon+s_i w_i)\\
        & w'Qw \le 0.05^2\\
        & \sum_i s_i w_i = 1 \\
        & w_i \le 0 && \forall i| s_i=-1\\ 
        & w_i \ge 0 && \forall i|s_i=+1 
\end{align}$$

Notes:

- $Q$ is hopefully positive definite.
- An initial point could be $w^0_i = s_i/n$.
- $w_i \le 0$ and $w_i \ge 0$ are bounds (opposed to general constraints).
- This is non-convex so you may get local optimal solutions when using a local solver.
- With some random data I see variables $w_i$ assuming an optimal value of zero. I.e. the problem can be interpreted to be unbounded. This may be an ill-posed problem.
- Maximization of this objective may make more sense. (No longer unbounded and now also convex).